# $\phi \mapsto \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\phi (x)}{\left \Vert x \right \Vert-1 + i\epsilon}$ is a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I want to show that
$$\phi \mapsto \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\phi (x)}{\left \Vert x \right \Vert-1 + i\epsilon}$$
is a distribution for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the Schwartz space and $\left \Vert \cdot \right \Vert$ the euclidean norm. I think that for the one dimensional case this should follow from the theory of Cauchy principle values but I'm not sure.

Comment: Would you mind explicitly defining the norm $\|\cdot\|_2$?

Comment: I've specified it. Here I mean the normel euclidean norm.

Answer (score 2):

First write the integral in polar coordinates, then one can argue that we only have to worry about the one dimensional case:
$$ \phi \mapsto \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{\phi(r)}{r-1+i\epsilon} dx ,$$
where $\phi:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb C$ is zero outside a small neirghborhood of $0$.

Let $\psi$ be a function which is $1$ in a small neighborhood of $1$, and zero outside a slightly larger neighborhood of $1$. Write
$$ \phi(r) = \phi_1(r) + \phi_2(r) ,$$
where
$$ \phi_2(r) = \psi(r) \left[ \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\phi^{(k)}(1)}{k!} (r-1)^k \right] ,$$
$$ \phi_1(r) = \phi(r) - \phi_2(r) ,$$
and compute the integral on each of the two parts.

I'll provide more details upon request.

Comment: How would you argue that it's enough to consider the one-dimensional case? If you do it via polar coordinates, don't forget that we also get a factor $r^{n-1}$ since $dx = r^{n-1} \, dr \, d\Omega$, where $d\Omega$ is the induced measure on $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{\phi(x)}{\|x\|-1+i\epsilon} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\psi(r)}{r-1+i\epsilon} \, dr$ where $\psi(r) = r^{n-1} \int_{S^{n-1}} \phi(r \omega) \, d\Omega(\omega)$.

Comment: and if $\phi$ is Schwarz, then so is $\psi$.